# I keep getting segmentation errors when I pass the capitol H flag through the command line, can anyone spot the segmentation error?

Tags: c

this is my main class that accepts a h or H command line parsing and should print the contents of a hexidecmal header

```
#include "p1-check.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
FILE *file;

elf_hdr_t h;
int c;

while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, ":if:hH")) != -1)
{
switch (c)
{
case 'h':
usage_p1(argv);
break;
case 'H':


file = fopen(optarg, "rb");
read_header(file, &h);
dump_header(h);
fclose(file);
break;
default:
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
break;
}
}
}
```

I have a program that takes in command line arguments and a path to an elf file and displays the content of them using a struct. The elf header file is set up to have 16 bytes. Of those bytes, every two bytes describes something else about the header (version, entry point, etc) and the last four bytes hold a magic number that tells you it's the end of the file. The bytes are all in hex.

```
bool read_header (FILE *file, elf_hdr_t *hdr)
{
    if (hdr != NULL && file != NULL && fread(hdr, sizeof(*hdr), 1, file) == 1)
    {
      fread(hdr, sizeof(*hdr), 1, file);
      if (hdr->magic == 0x00464C45)
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: always test if `file` is not `NULL`

Comment: why are you reading the header twice?

Comment: H seems to take no arguments, so optarg is undefined/not what you want

Comment: please [edit] your question to show the command line you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`H` option isn't followed by `:` so it doesn't accept an argument.

So `optarg` is not the elf filename you're expecting but rather a NULL or invalid pointer.

From the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html):

> optstring is a string containing the legitimate option characters.
> If such a character is **followed** by a colon, the option requires an
> argument, so getopt() places a pointer to the following text in the
> same argv-element

And since you're not checking the return value of `fopen` for `NULL` (which is probably is, as the file could not be opened), you're invoking undefined behaviour, when you're opening the file or when you're reading a null handle

To enable an argument for H option add a colon:

```
getopt (argc, argv, ":if:hH:"))
```

I'd also check how you're reading your elf header, as there are 2 `fread` calls, one in the test and one inside the condition.